# How to increase performance of finding Perfect numbers in range [Java Script]

Tags: javascript, algorithm

A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself. What are the ways to increase the performance of my algorithm?

```
function isPerfect(num) {
    const factors = [];
    for(let i =1; i < num -1; i++) {
        if(num%i == 0) {
         factors.push(i)
        }
    }
    if(factors.length >1) {
        return factors.reduce((prev,curr)=>prev+curr) === num
    }
}

function perfectsUpToN (n) {
    const perfects = []
    for(let i =0;i<n;i++) {
        if(isPerfect(i)) {
            perfects.push(i)
        }
    }
    return perfects
}
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't have to go from 1 - n. You can skip 1 because it is always a factor. You also only need to go up to the square root of n, but when you find a match, you need to push the divisor and the quotient to factors.

Comment: @bcr666 Hey, i refactored it a bit https://jsfiddle.net/nrkdygcf/2/ Could you exlpain why would i push a quotient to factors as well and why would we go up to sqrt(n), wouldn't we skip like 90% of numbers, in case of n = 10000.

Comment: Let's take 496 for example. Its perfect divisors are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248. The sqrt of 496 is 22.27, so 22. You know 1 is always there, so you can push that right away, and start looping from 2. 496 / 2 = 248 w/ remainder 0. So you push both 2 and 248 to your factors. That is why you push the quotient and divisor, one loop iteration got you two factors. As you can see, 4 will get you 124 and 8 will get you 62 and 16 will get you 31. Once you get to 22, the square root, there is nothing above 22 that is a perfect divisor, that you don't already have.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w09jcubt/1/ Please take a look at this, is there anything else i could do to improve performance?

Comment: There's so few of these numbers that it is easier and by far faster to just [hardcode the list of those fitting in the JS numeric range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers). Offers constant performance.

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious, just doing it for the sake of learning. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isPerfect(num) {
    const factors = new Set([1])
    for(let i =2; i < Math.sqrt(num-1); i++) {
        if(num%i === 0) {
            factors.add(i).add(num/i)
        }
    }
    return Array.from(factors).reduce((prev,curr)=>prev+curr) === num
}

function perfectsUpToN (n) {
    const perfects = []
    for(let i =0;i<n;i++) {
        if(isPerfect(i)) {
            perfects.push(i)
        }
    }
    return perfects
}

console.log(perfectsUpToN(10000))
```